# In fitting a linear mixed model, can the output be used to test the significance between my groups after taking into account the random effects?

Tags: r, mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, linear-model, biostatistics

Background for the data:
I have two continuous variables "AGD" and "Weight", a categorical variable with 7 levels "Litter size" and another categorical variable "Breeding_pair" with 4 levels. Basically weight is going to depend on litter size as the smaller the litter size the more nutrients an animal can get and so the bigger they will be and AGD will be bigger the more weight an animal has, however, how big a litter size is random, Breeding_pair is the parental pairs indicating what treatment they were from. and so I'm modeling AGD is dependent on the fixed effect weight + breeding pair + my random effect litter size.

NOTE: I have scaled and centered both AGD and weight so they both have mean 0 and SD 1.

My model:
I am using the "lme4" package in R the fit a model using the formula:

```r
M1 = lmer(AGD ~ Weight + Breeding_pair + (Weight|Litter Size), data = scaled_data_m)
```

using the output from this LMM is there a way to test if there is a significant difference in AGD after the litter size random effect has been taken into account? or is there a way to extract some coefficient that I can use to test if there is a significant difference in AGD between Breeding pairs after taking into account the randomness of the litter size?

Not sure if this matters by im using R4.3.0 and Rstudio 2021.09.0 Build 351

Comment: Is `lemr` a typo? Are you aware of the [emmeans package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/index.html)?

Comment: I'm not convinced that `Litter Size` should be the grouping variable of a random effect. "how big a litter size is random" does not necessarily translate to "it should be modelled as a random effect". `Breeding_pair` seems more likely to be a random effect but that depends on if you have repeated measures per breeding pair and with only four breeding pairs it's better to model that as a fixed effect anyway.

Comment: I do not have repeated measures for `Breeding_pair`, would that still be used as a fixed effect then? and yes my bad `lemr` should be `lmer`.

Comment: Can you encode the litter size as a numeric variable or is it truly categorical?

Comment: litter size can definitely be numerical if that will help the model i just assumed it would have been easier/better to have it as a categorical variable

Comment: How strong is the correlation of weight with litter size? What is AGD? Why did you scale?

Comment: Based on information provided fo far, I think I would start the analysis with `lm(AGD ~ weight * Breeding_pair)` and check model assumptions and performance. I'm not a huge fan of scaling and centering because it makes interpretation more difficult. If I incorporated `litter_size` then I would do so as a continuous variable, possibly transformed, and as a fixed effect. However, how to best deal with multi-collinearity depends on the goal of the modelling.